# How to add hyperlink to Amount (Decimal) column generated by bootstrap-table

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller

I want to add hyperlink on decimal type column without affect decimal format.

I have added hyperlink on text column, but for decimal column it is not display value in proper format.

Comment: can you provide what you have tried?

Comment: plz clarify you question with the code you have tried so one can track the mistakes and help you